Flyway migration not updating the columns for direct data insertion
I am using flyway script for migration of database. But during db initialization, I have added 3 rows in my table t1. Then with flyway migration v1, I have added 2 new rows in table t1. with v2, I have added two new rows in t1. Total rows are 7 now. With flyway script v3, I am adding new column in t1 and updating the default values for all 7 rows. While my new column are getting updated for 4 rows which I have inserted through migration scripts v1, v2 but the initial 3 rows are not getting updated with default values even though the query for updating is present in my flyway script version v3.
What could be the reason? How to fix this? Plz suggest?
This InitializeData class, called with SpringBootApplication, creating the initial table t1.
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InitializeData {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void loadData() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(false, false, "UTF-8", new ClassPathResource("/data.sql"));
        resourceDatabasePopulator.execute(dataSource);
    }
}

data.sql
INSERT INTO public.t1(
    event_name, event_description, created_by, created_dtm, updated_by, updated_dtm)
    VALUES
        ('e1', 'desc1', 'System', now(), 'System', now()),
        ('e2', 'desc2', 'System', now(), 'System', now()),
        ('e3', 'desc3', 'System', now(), 'System', now()))
       
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

ALTER TABLE public.t1 ADD COLUMN component_source VARCHAR(255);

-- Populate the new column with corresponding values
UPDATE public.t1 As target
SET component_source = CASE
    WHEN event_name = 'e1' THEN 'i1'
    WHEN event_name = 'e2' THEN 'i2'
    WHEN event_name = 'e3' THEN '13'
    WHEN event_name = 'e4' THEN 'i4'
    WHEN event_name = 'e5' THEN 'i5'
    WHEN event_name = 'e6' THEN 'i6'
    WHEN event_name = 'e7' THEN 'i7'
    
END
WHERE event_name IN (
    SELECT event_name
    FROM public.t1
);


1st guess is that your migrations run before the InitializeData. Add some printout and flyway verbosity however you can (I vaguely recall a migration callback can be added... so you could printout in there..). As to how to fix, I don't know. I hate Spring precisely for those loosing-control things.

I have got the fix. The case is data.sql overrides the value with null for the new columns. So, I have updated data.sql and added the new column in the script with default values, which fixed the issue. Now the value is set as required. Thanks all for the help.

if data.sql is supposed to run before the migrations, then your migration v3 will fail to add a column. BTW, your alter table (DDL) migration should never be along DML migration. Alter table commits automatically. So if the DML failed, like a connection loss or something else than bad sql, your migration transaction would not entirely rollback and flyway would retry it and fail forever until you manually edit table to drop the column.
